# send() function returns more bytes that it was required c++

Tags: c++, sockets, char, buffer

I am doing a socket program and, after my server is connected with the device, I am trying to send a message to him. But the send() function returns a number of bytes greater than the number of bytes that is stored on my array. And the message is not being sent.

Here is my code:

```
StartSendingMessages()
{
    int retorno;
    CString TextRetorno;

    HEX_bufferMessage = new CHAR[7]; // there are seven bytes

    // specifies the state
    HEX_bufferMessage[0] = 0xF0;
    HEX_bufferMessage[1] = 0x15;
    HEX_bufferMessage[2] = 0x31;
    HEX_bufferMessage[3] = 0x04;
    HEX_bufferMessage[4] = 0x02; // green
    HEX_bufferMessage[5] = 0x0E; // C1
    HEX_bufferMessage[6] = 0xF7;

    retorno = send(sckSloMo, HEX_bufferMessage, sizeof(HEX_bufferMessage), 0); 

    TextRetorno.Format("%d", retorno); // retorno = 8
    AfxMessageBox("Bytes enviados: " + TextRetorno);

    if (retorno == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Error Send!!");
        return;
    }
    else if(retorno != 0)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Send() OK !!");
    }
}
```

Anyone knows why is this happening??

Comment: Is the CHAR type a `char`? Is it possible that is wchar? try cout << sizeof(CHAR).

Answer (score 4):

You did not mean `sizeof(HEX_bufferMessage)`. The type of `HEX_bufferMessage` is [presumably] `char*`, and the size of a `char*` is 8 bytes on your [64-bit] system.

Pass the number `7` instead, preferably using a constant, and get rid of that dynamic allocation if the value `7` really is fixed.

```
const int BUF_SIZE = 7;
char HEX_bufferMessage[BUF_SIZE];

// ...

retorno = send(sckSloMo, &HEX_bufferMessage[0], BUF_SIZE, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of HEX_bufferMessage  is pointer to CHAR. You are using sizeof( HEX_bufferMessage ) that is equal to 8 in your paltform.

Comment: but why it is equal to 8 if I have an array with only seven positions?

Comment: @user2928858: Because you're not listening. `sizeof` isn't "get the number of elements in the array that this pointer points to". It's "get the size of this thing", and "this thing" is a pointer. A pointer is a single object value, of width 8 bytes on your system.

Comment: If you would declare CHAR HEX_bufferMessage[7]; then sizeof( HEX_bufferMessage ) indeed would be equal to 7. However you are using in fact sizeof( CHAR * ). It seems that in your platform sizeof( CHAR * ) is equal to 8,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got

`TYPE* myPointer;`

then `sizeof(myPointer)` will give you the size of the pointer (i.e. 4 bytes on a 32 bit system, 8 on a 64 bit system), **not** the size of the array.

You want to do

```
const int bufferSize = 7;
HEX_bufferMessage = new CHAR[bufferSize]; 

...

retorno = send(sckSloMo, HEX_bufferMessage, sizeof(CHAR) * bufferSize, 0);
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to `new` an array with small, fixed bound?

Comment: You wouldn't, assuming the bound is fixed - I'm just making as few changes to the original code as possible, to reduce confusion (since the error is due to the pointer definition)

Comment: Passing the fixed value 7 it works, the returned value is equal to 7. But the send() function still not working. =[

Comment: My device is a video server controller and to communicate with him I need to send messages in hexadecimal format. I am sending the messages like you saw, but it seems like he is not receiving or understanding them. I don't know what can be wrong...

Comment: Then it sounds like this is unrelated to your initial "sending the wrong number of bytes" question, so is beyond the scope here.  Presumably your message block isn't correct, but without knowing more about what you're doing, there's no way we can help.

Comment: At first I thought that this could be related with my problem, but now the send() function returns the correct number of bytes and the device doesn't show any changes after I run my program. I appreciate your help, benjymous. Thank you.

Comment: No problem :)   Please accept an answer, and come back when you get further on and find another code issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems you assume that `sizeof(HEX_buffer_message)` yields the number of elements in `HEX_buffer_message`. It doesn't. It produces the size of the type of `HEX_buffer_message` which seems to be a 64 bit pointer yielding `8` rather than `7`. There is no way to determine the size of an array allocated with `new T[n]` from the returned pointer. You'll need to use the `n` passed somehow.

Comment: `[It doesn't yield] the number of elements in HEX_buffer_message` Well, yes, it would, if `HEX_buffer_message` were an array and _had_ elements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: ... and the size of the elements were 1. Yes, there are cases where `sizeof(x)` does return the number of elements in `x` but the given example isn't one of them.